Oauth2-client password
I use oauth2-client dependency, and create an endpoint in my project, when I run the program and type that path in the browser it asks for login like when doing with spring-security, the problem is that my terminal doesn't show the password like when doing with spring securityenter image description here
I tried adding spring-security but it still doesn't work. It still doesn't show the password for me to log in.

A browser is not an OAuth2 client. At least, not without the help of a framework (Angular, React, Vue, ...) configured as a "public" OAuth2 client. I strongly suggest that you get some minimal OAuth2 background before rushing into Spring Security configuration...
